# how to make a Location Service Permission MessageBox

Tags: windows-phone-7, location, messagebox

I have submited a App but is not certified because this:

"This application uses the Location Service API to determine a user's location and show them events taking place nearby
however, it does not appear to contain a privacy policy that is accessible to users explaining how the application uses the
Location Service API."

And what i want to do is something like this

[image]

When user clicks in Policty Statement open a new window with settings page with my app location policies.

Can anyone help me? How can i add a link like in image?

Cumps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can navigate to a page using the Hyperlink control

```
<Textblock>
  <Hyperlink NavigateUri="/PrivacyPage.xaml" 
             TargetName="_blank">Privacy Statement</Hyperlink>
</Textblock>
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.navigateuri%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for more info

I don't think you can put a hyperlink in a call to MessageBox.Show() though so you have to create your own Messagebox-like page.
The first time the app is launched you direct the user to your message page. E.g. using this in MainPage.xaml

```
OnNavigatedTo(...) 
{
  if(!AppSettings.HasMessageBeenShown)
  {
    AppSettings.HasMessageBeenShown=true;
    NavigationContext.Navigate(new Uri("/MessagePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
  }
}
```